# Simple separation steering

Tags: java

I' ve a java application that creates 150 random rectangles with random width, height, X- and Y- coordinate.

Most of them are overlapping and this is my problem. I want to seperate all the rectangles, but I don' t know what I have to do.
Here you see a screenshot of the rects:

[image]

All rects are stored in an ArrayList (`private ArrayList<DungeonCell> dungeonCells;`)
The DungeonCell-Class is something like a vector with the following fields:

```
public int positionX;
public int positionY;

public int width;
public int height;
```

I hope that you understand my problem.

Comment: What is your task? To separate all rectangles into groups so that in one group there are only overlapping rectangles? Or something else is meant?

Comment: Are rectangles aligned to axis or do you have rotation as well? If the first one is the case problem is pretty trivial and I won't give you hint, if the second one than google: _Separate Axis Theorem_.

Comment: Or you want to generate rectangles so that there will be no overlapping rectangles?

Comment: I want to move all the rectangles sothat they doesn't overlapping each other.

Comment: In this case you can use the advice from one of the responses: just generate rectangles one by one. If a new rectangle intersects any other from previously generates ones, just regenerate it.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of adding the triangles without any concern, first check if it fits. If not, skip it and create another one. This would be possible with a `do-while`.

```
Rectangle r;
do
{
   r = createRandomRect();
} while (overlaps(r))
add(r);
```

**Note:** This is going to be very slow if the amount of rectangles keeps increasing and the available space gets smaller and smaller. Also make sure that rectangles are not occupying the whole area. This algorithm may fail if there literally all space is used, but this is unlikely, since you work with floats, I think.

Comment: That's going to exhibit pretty bad time complexity as the number of rectangles increases...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I know. I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Not really if `overlaps` method will query only nearby rectangles.

Comment: @Leri: The queries are one thing (and can be solved with quad-trees or whatever).  But it's also the retry ratio.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Yes, you're right. Also it will matter bounds for rectangle container is defined or not. Question definitely is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid generating overlapping random rectangles you can do this:

- Generate the values for your next rectangle
- Check if any of the corners of the new rectangle lies within any of the existing rectangles
- Then either add the rectangle or generate new random values
- Don't forget to avoid infinite loops by setting a maximum number of tries!

Comment: Your overlap check logic is broken. What if you have two squares inside each other?

Comment: You have a point, if Thomas Flynn wants to allow rectangles inside rectangles. From the variable name "dungeonCells" I guess he wants only rectangles that are positioned next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check whether two rectangles intersect each other you need to write something like the following:

```
public static boolean Intersects(Rectangle rect1, Rectangle rect2)
{
    if (rect1.positionX >= rect2.positionX && 
rect1.positionY>=rect2.positionY && 
rect1.positionX <= rect2.positionX+rect2.height && 
rect1.positionY <= rect2.positionY + rect2.width 
  || rect1.positionX+rect1.height >= rect2.positionX 
&& rect1.positionY+rect1.width>=rect2.positionY 
&& rect1.positionX+rect1.height <= rect2.positionX+rect2.height 
&& rect1.positionY+rect1.width <= rect2.positionY + rect2.width)
        return true;
    else return false;
}
```